# How do I get "Can't Feel a Thing"?

Tags: borderlands-2

The Can't Feel a Thing challenge in Caustic Caverns requires you to stand in the acid pools for 30 seconds without entering Fight for your Life mode. When I first got a shield immune to Corrosion damage I thought I cracked the secret. Surprisingly, corrosive-immune shields don't actually protect you from the acid. And at level 38 the acid is still quite painful even in Playthrough 1.

How do I get this challenge? Do I need max level and a crazy shield or is there some trick to it? FWIW I'm a Siren and could conceivably boost up a Turtle Shield with skills and a Class Mod but ideally I'd like to know a way all characters can do this.

Comment: Have you tried to determine the shield DPS for the acid?

Comment: @horatio IIRC around 500-1000 per second, I'll check it out tonight.

Answer (score 8):

I looked into this a little bit (youtube) and it appears that your understanding of the challenge is incorrect: you need to "not go into Last Stand Mode" rather than "not break Shield."

So you need a high level shield and a high high health value. I play as Salvador, and in my case, especially with some skills upgrade, when I activate the Gunzerker skill, my health bar recovers faster than I take damage.

So if you have a health regen skill, activate it right when the shield goes down, and this may delay your death.

( see: [http: // www.youtube.com/ watch?v= ZOHBabyZmr8](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZOHBabyZmr8) @ 1:20 )

Comment: Maybe that was it; I'll have to check the description and see what kind of health regen I can get out of my skills...nothing quite that simple for Siren.

Comment: IIRC in that particular video, the player lost 1400 Shields and about 1400 HP. I didn't notice any skill activations. At lvl 38, you probably have access to higher shield values. I think I have about a 2400 unit Shield and am currently leveled in the mid-20s

Comment: Well, it's no where near THAT easy unless you're a Gunzerker with the skill that reduces damage when Gunzerking. I took more like 15,000 damage (plus the health I was regenerating during that time), but I did get it with insane shields and the best of my class's shield/heath skills.

Answer (score 3):

It is not cumulative, I just tested this. I'm level 26 and can survive about 24 seconds, tried this several times (without falling into fight for life) and didn't pass the challenge.

However you are right that there is a bug. Not 5 minutes after failing to get it normally I got it by standing on a rock barely above the 'waterline'.

My crosshairs show where I was standing in this image. https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRjH4.jpg

It appears that if you are close enough to the acid it still counts you as being in it for the purposes of the challenge even though you're not taking damage. This would explain why some people are getting it when stepping in and out making it look cumulative.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way I found was deal with this challenge later on. I tried doing it in play through two but the damage is scaled and it hurts like hell. I lasted around 20 seconds or so. I went back into play through one and tried it there after I was level 50. The acid did maybe 1/3 of my shield and I had the challenge.

Answer (score 2):

Confirmed. You do not have to stand in the corrosive ooze for 30 seconds straight. Just step in, step out before the corrosive damage will drain your health to 0, let your shields/health recharge, and repeat until you get the challenge.

Comment: Well done! If this indeed is true...

Answer (score 0):

The wording of the Challenge says:

> Stand in the corrosive ooze for 30 seconds without falling into Fight
>   for Your Life

Notice those 30 seconds aren't necessarily *consecutive*, just *cumulative*. So I believe you can muck around in the ooze in shifts to get the achievement. I got it as Zero, so the Salvador tanking build and special items are unnecessary.

**NOTE**: Someone please test this for me. Unless I somehow bugged it, I got this achievement completely by accident and couldn't figure out how - this is my only explanation. I definitely could not have survived for 30 consecutive seconds in the ooze as I was only a level 19 Zero and had no special gear on to mitigate damage or regen health. I just tested it and died within 15. I can't test completing the challenge myself because I've already completed it and rerolling a character for it will take a few days.

Comment: I also randomly got this as Zero.  There is absolutely no way I could have survived a full 30 seconds.  It must be either cumulative or bugged.  My money is on bugged.

Comment: I don't think this is cumulative, pretty sure it only works consecutive. @OrigamiRobot it worked for me, get a great shield and use your best shield/health/damage reduction skills and test it on playthrough 1.

Comment: I rolled a Siren to test this and so starts the week-long leveling grind...

Answer (score 0):

Level 50 Psycho, went back to Normal and stood in the acid for over 3 minutes straight (Rough Rider Shield, Release The Beast/Badass Psycho Mutant special ability to completely refill health and receive damage reduction).  I probably could have made 5 minutes, but I got bored.  The point is, I still didn't get the achievement.  This thing is bugged as hell.  Sometimes you get it for 3 seconds in the acid, sometimes you get it 2 minutes after spending 10 seconds in the acid, and sometimes you stand there for over 3 minutes and nothing happens.  I have this achievement on every other character, and got it by chance every time.  Just keep going back and getting yourself acid-ed up while running around killing stuff.  Eventually it'll pop.